# Can't install robotframework?

Tags: pip, robotframework

I've tried with these two ways:

1. pip install robotframework, return with below error:

> Collecting robotframework Using cached robotframework-2.8.7.tar.gz
>   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "", line 20, in    File
>   "C:\Users\wul5\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-
>   6d1rilfl\robotframework\setup.py", line 45    for directory in 'rebot',
>   'libdoc', 'testdoc', 'lib', 'common'
>                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6d1rilfl\robotframework

2. Download the source file, and install with 
   python setup.py install, get below error:

> File "setup.py", line 51 for directory in 'rebot', 'libdoc',
>   'testdoc', 'lib', 'common':
>                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Anyone can help?

Comment: what version of python are you using? Also, does `python -m pip install robotframework` fail in the same way?

Comment: Yes. It could be the reason of version mismatching between python and robotframework module.

Comment: Are you using python 3.x?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 3.4.3. Which version I can used to install robotframework?

Comment: I reinstall python version 2.7, then robot framework can install success.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps to install robotframework

> Install Python 2.7.1

RIDE runs only on the regular Python, not on Jython nor IronPython.

Download Python 2.7.1

Install Python 2.7.1.

Set the path in environment variable. (Look below for instructions )

Note: Python 2.6 is the minimum version.  Robot Framework, RIDE does not yet support Python3  .

> Set path on Windows 8 (Windows 7 users also can try the steps)

Open  Start

Type  Environment Variables ( this will search directly )

Click on  Edit the system environment variables

Goto  Advanced tab

Click on   Environment Variables  button

Scroll down under  System variables  and click on Path

Click on  Edit  button

Append  `;<InterpreterInstallationDir>;<InterpreterInstallationDir>\Scripts\` in variable value
Save the changes.

If command prompt is already open, then re-open command prompt to effectively take changes.

> Install wxPython 2.8.12.1

It is necessary to install wxPython because RIDE’s GUI is implemented by  using wxPython.

Download wxPython 2.8.12.1 directly from [here][1]

Run the installer and finish the setup. 
This will install wxPython 2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1  on your system.

> Install PIP 1.1

To install PIP follow the step by step instruction provided here http://arunrocks.com/guide-to-install-python-or-pip-on-windows/

> Install Robotframework 2.9rc1
>
> > Using Command Prompt

You can install RIDE by using the `pip`  or  `easy_install`  commands.

Run either of the following command to  install Robotframework:

```
        pip install robotframework ride

        easy_install robotframework ride
```

After the installation of RIDE, run the following command:

```
    `ride.py`    (this will launch RIDE )
```

> > Using Windows Installer

Download robotframework-RIDE 1.4:

You can download RIDE installer for windows version from

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/robotframework-ride/robotframework-ride-1.4.tar.gz

Open the installer and follow the onscreen instructions.
After installation, launch RIDE by double clicking the shortcut icon.

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Robot framework is not compatible with Python 3.x yet. 
https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/Installation#Python_installation

> Starting from Robot Framework 2.5, Python 2.5 is the minimum supported Python version. Earlier versions support also Python 2.3 and 2.4. Robot Framework is currently not compatible with Python 3.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

If pip is not able to install robot framework and ride then try this,

`sudo easy_install robotframework-ride`

Comment: This question wasn't about robotframework-ride. The problem was that they were trying to use python3 before robot had been made to work with python3.